# java calculate faculty of an inserted number

Tags: java, numbers

Hey so I need to calculate the faculty of a number that i inserted into my first textfield but when I click the button it gives me 0. Can someone help plz? greatly appreciated. I'm also not good in java so if u see something to improve plz share :)

FIX DOWN BELOW

Comment: You never call `faculteit`, and `fac` is not initialized, so it will remain 0 even if you call that method.

Comment: Does "faculty" mean "factorial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize the fac variable using the faculty method first.Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(textFiled1.getText());//keep in mind that if the text is not a number this will give you an error
    fac = faculty(temp);
    textField2.setText("" + fac);
}
```

Also you must modify the faculty method:

```
TextField textField1, textField2;
Button btn;
static int fac;
public static int faculteit(int n) {
    int temp = 1;//this is a temporal variable that we use to compute the output of this method
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        temp*= i;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: @Viktor This code should work, maybe you have some other parts of code you want to show us?

Comment: @Viktor make `fac` inside `faculteit` method a local variable and initialize it to 1. (i.e. add `int fac = 1;` to the beginning of that method)

Comment: @Eran Yes you are right i forgot to mention that part.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize fac variable to 1.
You are multiplying numbers with 0 and it is returning result as 0.

Inside faculteit method and before for loop,

```
fac = 1;
```